# Why did Asuka get her right eye injured but Shinji didn't?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

In the second episode of *Evangelion*, we can see that Shinji's Eva's right eye is injured by the Third Angel, but nothing happens to his right eye. But when it comes to Asuka's Eva getting her right eye injured by a Lance of Longinus in *End of Evangelion*, it also injures her right eye. How can this happen?

[image: Shinji's eva]
[image: Asuka's Eva]

Comment: I think the thing is that the shot above was just some energy weapon, nothing (too) special, but the Longinus spear is very connected to the nature of these robots, so it was able to also harm the synchronized pilot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a matter of synchronization rates. Shinji was clearly not well-synchronized to Unit-01 when he fought Sachiel in episode 1, whereas Asuka was extremely well-synchronized to Unit-02 when she fought the MP Evas in _End_, and hence she sympathetically suffered far more of the damage Unit-02 took.

Comment: ^what this guy said, the higher the synchronization rate, the higher the chance for the pilot to emulate the damage the EVA receives

Comment: See also https://wiki.evageeks.org/Synchronization

Comment: another theory is that it's possible the Lance has "special powers" to inflict damage

Comment: @paulnamida bur how can mari in evangelion movie 2 her eva's eye were got injured when she is in eva's berserk mode by the angel but nothings happen with mari's eye...

Comment: @Gagantous was that at the fight at the start of the movie?? It's been a long time since I watched that movie and I don't think I remember the full details, but iirc that was a special mode dubbed "the beast" right?? I always thought it was a forced berserk form, without relying on synchronization. It's been a long time though, I could be wrong

Comment: Yes it's called "the beast" @paulnamida

Comment: @Gagantous so I was remembering it correctly then, in that case, I stand by my interpretation that "the beast" mode is artificial and not really linked to the usual high synchro-rate berserk mode that happens by accident and not willingly

Answer (score 1):

The Lance of Longinus is not a normal weapon like it mobilized Lilith and it just overpowers Lilith and Adam which are the seeds of life of Angels and humans so I suppose it can harm the pilot if it hits the Eva It has that power and what makes this theory true and the synchronization one wrong is that if it wasnt asuka would be so dead, the harm caused by the other new evas to unit02 is so massive like her guts were out of her

Comment: you could add more link/reff to make your answer more reliable

Answer (score 0):

If you've watched any other movies out anime series that have some sort of synchronisation between the human and a bigger robot (e.g. Pacific Rim and Darling In The Franxx) the concept that since the human is one with the thing they're connected to they will lose sense of their own feeling and only feel what the thing they're connected to is feeling externally, and since in Evangelion the Longinus Spear is something to stop Angels in their paths instantly and since Evas are Angel carcass basically, the Longinus Spear will have the same effect on the Eva, and since Asuka was linked to her Eva the Spear had dealt damage that an Angel would normally take to her Eva dealing the same damage to Asuka too.